# python print contents from wx.ListCtrl

Tags: io, wxpython, listctrl

I have a list created as

```
self.statusListCtrl = wx.ListCtrl(self.panelUpper, -1, style=wx.LC_REPORT|wx.SUNKEN_BORDER)
```

I add data to this list using

```
self.statusListCtrl.Append([datetime.datetime.now(),action,result])
```

When my process is all done I have a nice list showing things that were tried, the result of that attempt and a datetime stamp.  Now what I want to do is output that to a text file.  my problem is that I cant get the data from my listctrl correctly.

This is how I am trying to iterate through the list.

```
fileName = 'd:\ssplogs\sspInstaller.log'
FILE = open(fileName,"w")

for itemIdx in range(0,self.statusListCtrl.GetItemCount()):
    line = str(self.statusListCtrl.GetItemText(itemIdx) + "\n")            
    print "line" , line        
    writeLine = line
    FILE.write(writeLine)

FILE.close()
```

The output I am getting though is only my datetime stamp, which is the first column of my list.  How do I get this so I see something like

```
datetime, action, result
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this to get Row x Column data:

```
self.list.GetItem(row, col).GetText()
```

Working example:

```
import wx

class MainWindow(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self)

        self.list = wx.ListCtrl(self.panel, style=wx.LC_REPORT)
        self.list.InsertColumn(0, "Date")
        self.list.InsertColumn(1, "Action")
        self.list.InsertColumn(2, "Result")

        for a in range(5):        
            self.list.Append(["Date %d" % a, "Action %d" % a, "Result %d" % a])

        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer()
        self.sizer.Add(self.list, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND)

        self.panel.SetSizerAndFit(self.sizer)
        self.Show()

        # Save
        for row in range(self.list.GetItemCount()):
            print(", ".join([self.list.GetItem(row, col).GetText() for col in range(self.list.GetColumnCount())]))

app = wx.App(False)
win = MainWindow(None)
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: How would you assign the value for the print(", ".join....) command to a variable?

Comment: I changed print(...) to line=str(...) and now I can both print and write it to a file.  Thanks much

Comment: @ccwhite1 - You can do just `line = ", ".join([self.list.GetItem(row, col).GetText() for col in range(self.list.GetColumnCount())])`. Or you can use just `for` loop instead of not very readable list comprehension.